# Is there a way to see the maximum memory use of an iOS app since it started up?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory-management, instruments

If there is an app and we started it up, we can use Instruments to look at the memory usage second by second, but what if during initialization, the memory shot up to 60MB for a split second, and then come back down? (such as a few large graphics contexts and bitmaps and CALayers).

Is there a way to see the maximum since the app started up?  I thought of a caveman way, which is to add a dummy loop of, say a million or 10 million, after we have allocated the large graphics context and bitmaps and CALayers, so that the memory use is constant for a few seconds, and can be seen in Instruments.

But then it should be better that if there are 5 layers, we should allocate one graphics context, get the bitmap, and set it to the layer, and immediately release the graphics context since it is not needed any more.  And then we go on to the next graphics context, bitmap, and layer, and so on, instead of creating five graphics contexts, bitmaps, and release all five at the end.  But to do the cavemen method, we need to add the dummy loop to all five places before each release.  Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Why not add (for dev purposes only) a block that is put on the main queue, computes the memory usage, then essentially schedules itself on the main queue again (and again and again) for say 2 to 5 seconds. Most of your memory would be allocated on the main queue, so you essentially snapshot every runloop call for some period of time.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Leaks or Allocations template and select the Allocations instrument. There is a graph next to the Allocations instrument. Click the timeline above the graph and hold the mouse button down. When you drag along the timeline, Instruments will show you the total amount of memory allocated at that point of time.

The difference between the Leaks and Allocations templates is the Leaks template sets the Allocations instrument to track all allocations while the Allocations template sets the Allocations instrument to track only active allocations.

Comment: if the memory allocation happened in less than a second, and the graph is logged every second, can the graph miss it?

Comment: The graph is logged more often than every second. If you drag along the timeline, a tool tip appears that shows the time relative to the start of recording. You'll see the time can display fractions of milliseconds. The chances of your app allocating memory faster than Instruments can track it are slim.

Comment: I was thinking that if the graph can log 10 points in a second, which is 0.1 second each, but the CPU is running at 1GHz or on the Simulator, at 2.6GHz, so let's say it is a billion operations per second, and 100 million operations per 0.1 second, and a lot can happen in between that 0.1 second interval